# Matrix in SL(2)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A\in SL(2, \mathbb{R})$, the group of $2\times2$ real matrices with determinat $1$. 
Is it true that $\|A\|=\|A^{-1}\|$, where $\|\cdot\|$ is the usual matrix norm induced by the usual euclidean norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Why don't you compute the inverse of a general matrix with determinant 1 and see?

Comment: Recall that one can get the inverse of a $2\times 2$ matrix by multiplying by the inverse of the determinant and rearranging the entries (and adding some minuses).

Answer (score 1):

After some research, here goes an answer to finish the topic.

The norm of $A$ is the biggest singular value of $A$, that is, the biggest eigenvalue of $A^TA$ (once $A$ is real), that is, the biggest root of 
$$
p_A(\lambda):=\lambda^2-tr(A^TA)\lambda+det(A^TA).
$$

A calculation shows that $p_A(\lambda)=p_{A^{-1}}(\lambda)$, from where the answer is affirmative.

Answer (score 0):

As in your own answer, use that $\|A\|$ is the largest of the (positive) eigenvalues of the symmetric matrix $A^TA$. Now being diagonalisable with mutually inverse eigenvalues (as $A^TA\in SL(2,\Bbb R)$), this matrix is similar to its inverse $A^{-1}(A^T) ^{-1}$, which is similar to $(A^T)^{-1}A^{-1}=(A^{-1})^TA^{-1}$. Therefore $\|A\|$ is the largest of the eigenvalues of $(A^{-1})^TA^{-1}$, which is $\|A^{-1}\|$.